# Tool for detecting Javascripts events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Do you know a tool or plugin (for Mozilla or iExplorer) that shows Javascript's **fired events** while an user is navigating and interacting with a web page?.

Comment: Doesn't firebug do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure the de facto standard is [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/), it has a plugin for firefox and a lite version for IE, you can enalbe it on a website, turn on the console tab and click profiling, do some action and click again and you can see every event that occurs with many more details.

Comment: I tested it... It shows the functions that had been called between profiler's start and stop... but, how can it help me to know if a jQuery action like .blur() .change() .click() etc has been called?

Comment: In the same way, stated by yourself, profiler can catch all the events if I understand you

Comment: I got the events, but they are from a very low level... I can't understand where does the blur() appears... everything I see is like "CreateCallBack", "handle" etc. How can I decide when does a high level start and stop?

Comment: in the Script tab click on the button in the leftmost upper corner which is Break On Next button. it will break on the next event that fires, in addition you can set breakpoints, watch variables, see the stack trace and ...

Comment: It shows me a poor indented javascript code unusable for debug purposes... jeje

Comment: probably you use a minified version of a library, you should replace it with development version in debugging environment

Comment: I'm working with jquery libraries from Microsoft... I do not know if I can change that....

Comment: No, you don't need to do that, just look for development version to download, e.g. if you look at jquery homepage there is two options for download a minifide(compressed) version and a development version that is readable

Answer (score 3):

There is a good one, but it works only with [Dev Channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) version of Chrome: [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl?hl=hu)

This extension is not only displaying the JavaSript events, but measures all rendering events related to the web page.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug in IE too. You have to untick the option **disable script debugging** in Tools -> Advanced options - > Disable script debugging (internet explorer). The best tool for debugging JavaScript on Internet Explorer is the Microsoft Script Editor, a free component of Microsoft Office XP/2003

**Firebug** and Venkman's are good ones to work if you are working in Mozilla based browsers.

You can view a list of javascript debuggers here

[Debuggers](http://www.ajaxpath.com/ajax-debuggers/)